# How to uninstall Android App with root permissions?

Tags: android, apk, root, uninstallation

I wrote something to uninstall (delete) an App and have now the problem that the apk seems to be deleted but the app is not really deleted from phone..

The supposedly deleted app still exists in the launchers app drawer. And I can open the app, but it force closes the app.

I tested the procedure with an own App (existing at /data/app, not /system/app).
With systemapps I didn't test.

Here the code:

```
private void delApp() {
    String deleteCMD = "rm " + packageInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir;


    Process process;
    try 
    {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("mount -o remount,rw -t rfs /dev/stl5 /system; \n");          
        os.writeBytes(deleteCMD+"; \n");
        os.writeBytes("mount -o remount,ro -t rfs /dev/stl5 /system; \n");
        os.flush();

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }      



}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't rightly know why what you're doing does not work, maybe someone else can shed some light on that.

You could try:

```
pm uninstall com.package.name
```

instead of your `rm /package/dir/path` method

I'm not sure if that works on apps in the `/system/app directory`, however.

Also, take a look at: [Application launcher icon is not deleted from Home screen when uninstalling android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339390/application-launcher-icon-is-not-deleted-from-home-screen-when-uninstalling-andr)

Comment: Thank you, App is deleted correctly and doesn't appear in launcher. :-)

Comment: @freibergisch You're welcome. If you're satisfied with my answer, please accept it using the checkmark to the left.