# how to uninstall apps on my rooted phone

Tags: android, uninstallation, rooted-device

I tried to uninstall apps on my rooted phone,and I usethe code from [How to uninstall Android App with root permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661782/how-to-uninstall-android-app-with-root-permissions) ,and I tried the suggestion but I failed.
Here is my code:

```
Process process;
try {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
    os.writeBytes("pm uninstall com.lixiancheng.orangemusic"+"; \n");
    os.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why i can't uninstall the app?is any problem with the code?

Comment: I don't think \n is valid here.

Comment: I tried to remove these \n,failed again.

Answer (score 1):

Have You tried:

```
try {
    Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

    outputStream.writeBytes("pm uninstall com.lixiancheng.orangemusic\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
    outputStream.flush();
    su.waitFor();
} catch(IOException e){
    throw new Exception(e);
} catch(InterruptedException e){
    throw new Exception(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Type adb shell rm -f/{data,system}/app/APKNAME”, replace “APKNAKE” with the name of the application you want to delete and press Enter.