# How to remove System App if device is Rooted

Tags: android

I'm writing a Uninstall App. I want to remove System App, of course my phone is Rooted. I use code from [How to uninstall Android App with root permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661782/how-to-uninstall-android-app-with-root-permissions).

```
private void delApp() {
    String deleteCMD = "pm " + applicationInfo.packageName;
    Process process;
    try 
    {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("mount -o remount,rw -t rfs /dev/stl5 /system; \n");          
        os.writeBytes(deleteCMD+"; \n");
        os.writeBytes("mount -o remount,ro -t rfs /dev/stl5 /system; \n");
        os.flush();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }      
}
```

but my phone Toast a message "... has been Granted super User Permissons" and not remove app I choosed. I try with both User App and System App but not different. What am I missing ? How to remove System App with Root permissons and How to remove App without this Dialog (fast remove and automaticaly).

[image]

**EDIT**
I solved my problem using this code, hope it help someone.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("mount -o rw,remount /system\n");
os.writeBytes("rm -r "+ "[SourceDir]" + "\n");  
os.writeBytes("mount -o ro,remount /system\n");
os.flush();
os.close();
process.waitFor();
```

note: [SourceDir] is your system app directory

Comment: Did you solve this problem? If yes, please share the answer

Comment: @MustafaChelik see my edit, hope it help you

Comment: If you've found the answer yourself, the "Stack overflow way" is to create an answer to your own question instead of editing the answer into the question.

Comment: So, you mean I can remove an application just by running "rm -fr /system/app/test_app" command, right?!