# The method getExternalFilesDir() is undefined for the type Environment?

Tags: android, environment

I'm using Android version is 4.2

I want to get the path of a stored file by using this

```
String file = Environment.getExternalFilesDir() + "/"+title+".zip"
```

I get this error:

```
The method getExternalFilesDir() is undefined for the type Environment
```

However, the Environment class does have this method, why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getExternalFilesDir()` is a method of `Context`.

[Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) has other methods, but not that one.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124040/752320) explains the difference between them, also.

Comment: this is very weird, dont get it why google keep this method to `context` while other methods such as getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(),getExternalStorageDirectory() to Envirnoment.

Comment: Probably because the `files` directory is application-specific, while regular external storage is available to all to read/write.