# Android | obtain the sdcard (removable) path

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I've tried a lot of method and I've read a lot of posts, without find a valid soluction.

Summing:

I try to use this https://github.com/18446744073709551615/android-file-chooser-dialog to choose a directory and use it. This code work perfectly with internal storage.

With this code: `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")`, on my Asus TF201 with JellyBean and with Lollipop, I have `/storage/sdcard1` and I can use this with previus code and it works.

Now, the problem.
I've tried with this (and other similar solution): [How can I get external SD card path for Android 4.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0) but on LG G3 with Android 6.0 I've `/mnt/media_rw/9014-4EF8` and doesn't work with previous code.

How can I obtain the external sd path? I need only to read in sd. Or can I use `/mnt/media_rw/9014-4EF8`?

Comment: You do not have arbitrary read access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android devices that ship with Android 4.4+.

Comment: On my (old) tablet I've Android 5.1.1 and `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")` works perfectly... But how can some app (like file explorer) can read on write on sd card?

Comment: Have a look at getExternalFileDirs().

Comment: @greenapps sure that can help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123812/diff-between-getexternalfilesdir-and-getexternalstoragedirectory

Comment: Read carefully. I said ...FilesDirs(). Not ...FilesDir().

Comment: I am facing same issue, please suggest some solution..